# How to change the value of a select tag on a select tag's onchange event. html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need to check when a select tag's value change if it is equal to say "NA" if so it needs to change the other select tag's value to something different and or disable it?

I am working with php. If there is a way in php let me know. Please

```
<html>
<center>
<title>Testing</title>
<head>
<script>
function closeWin()
{
alert('Posted');
window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
}
//Function to test value and change value
function value()
{
if (Question4DDL == 'NA')
{
Question5DDL == 'NA'
}
{


}
</script>
</head>
<form name="input" action="index.php" method="post" >

<body>
<div id="Questions">
<table>
<tr><td>
<div id="Q1">Subscribed to service provider?</div>
</td>
<td>
<select Name="Question1DDL">
   <option value = 'BLANK'></option> 
<option value = 'YES'>YES</option>
    <option value ='NO'>NO</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="Q2">Which provider are you currently with?</div>
</td>
<td>
<select Name="Question2DDL">
<option value = 'BLANK'></option> 
    <option>t1</option>
    <option>t2</option>
    <option>t3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="Q3">Type of dwelling/premisis?</div>
</td>
<td>
<select Name="Question3DDL">
<option value = 'BLANK'></option> 
    <option>CLUSTER</option>
    <option>FLAT</option>
    <option>PLOT</option>
    <option>TOWNHOUSE</option>
    <option>FARM</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="Q4">Alarm in working order?</div>
</td>
<td>

//select tag in question.
<select Name="Question4DDL" onchange="value()">
<option value = 'BLANK'></option> 
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    <option value = 'NA'>(N/A) - No Alarm</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="Q5">Age of alarm?</div>
</td>
<td>
<select Name="Question5DDL">
<option value = 'BLANK'></option> 
    <option>-1</option>
    <option>-3</option>
    <option>+3</option>
</select>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="Q6">Paying more than R350 per month?</div>
</td>
<td>
<select Name="Question6DDL"><option value = 'BLANK'></option> 
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="Q7">Is the prospect in a known response area? (Have they seen sign boards in their area?)</div>
</td>
<td>
<select Name="Question7DDL">
<option value = 'BLANK'></option> 
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="Q8">Request site visit from agent?</div>
</td>
<td>
<select Name="Question8DDL">
<option value = 'BLANK'></option> 
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<textarea name="comments"  rows="5">
</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input name="sb1" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="closeWin()">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
</body>
</form>
</center>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your code and what have you tried?

Comment: Please provide code that you're working with. If you use jQuery.

Comment: check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3EezN/19/

Answer (score 1):

first you get user input which is select by user.
After that using that input you will used if condition like if service provider is yes then execute if loop and display other option that you want to display otherwise follow further procedure you will provide.
I don't know PHP so here i give description otherwise i make code that first get user input and then proceed.